# Factorial using Ruby

Tags: ruby

I am pretty new to Ruby and I am trying to create a method that returns the factorial of a number. I have the logic in my head, I know how it works but, I am missing something so it could work in Ruby. when running my code:

```
def factorial(num)
  n = num
  if n == 0
    1
  end
  n * factorial(num - 1)
end
```

I keep on getting this error:  `` stack level too deep
    from: (pry):327:in `factorial' ``

I have read a bit about it in previous threads and I know it has to do with me not differentiating my method's argument and my variable `n`/`num`. I just haven't been able to figure out how to solve it and why my solution doesn't work when assigning the value of `num` to a new variable `n`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
def factorial(num)
  n = num
  if n == 0
    1
  else   # ⇐ HERE
    n * factorial(num - 1)
  end
end
```

The issue you had is that `n * factorial(num - 1)` (recursive call) was nevertheless executed *even* for non-positive `n`.

I believe, that so-called “earlier return” would make this code more readable:

```
def factorial(num)
  return 1 unless num > 0
  num * factorial(num - 1)
end
```

Please note, that you actually don’t need an additional variable `n`, `num` perfectly works.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The second approach DOES make a lot of sense. I will practice a lot more on this. :)

Comment: Or `return 1 if num < 1`

Comment: Also I believe the proper term is a "guard clause" when it is the first line used to avoid a nested condition. Where as an "early return" would be mid method body (but I quibble) :)

Comment: @engineersmnky now I am puzzled as well :) I treat “guard” as something that is applied to the function itself, like in [tag:erlang].

Comment: @MarkThomas well, yes, I though about that but for some reason my variant seems _more explicit in terms of factorial function_ to me. The comparison should be done against zero, not against 1 IMHO.

Comment: @mudasobwa I don't come up with the jargon ( for which everyone should be grateful :)

Comment: OK, `return 1 if num <= 0` :)

Answer (score 3):

Recursive functions are somewhat risky because they tend to result in "stack flow too deep" errors even when functioning normally. They also tend to be slow, and it is almost always possible to express the concept in a loop.

Here's a more *ruby-esque* implementation of the factorial:

```
class Integer

  def !
    [self,1].max.downto(1).inject(&:*)
  end

end
```

And here it is  in action:

> 5.!
>       => 120

This isn't perfect, because it is unfortunately not possible to define a real postfix operator (ruby doesn't have any) to just do `5!`. In reality, I would probably use `Integer.factorial` or `Integer.bang` as the name. "Bang-methods" also typically signify somewhat dangerous operations that modify the receiver, although at least the danger always lurks with the factorial function: `100000000.!` will easily bring down a system.